# Import JS modules in client side of a node.js app

Tags: node.js

What is the standard way to import JS modules on the client side of a node.js app?

It seems bad to add `<script src="..."></script>`, but I don't see what else I can do.

**Update:**

Here is the code of the server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And the client:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> (doesn't work)
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your index.js:

```
var module = require('module');

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { module : module});
    //Now your EJS will have the module
}
```

Comment: So I have to put my file in node_modules? Imagine I want to import jQuery for instance.

Comment: Err, I don't think you want to import a jQuery module into the EJS file. If you want to import modules, my answer above works. If you are trying to use jQuery, you should stick with the `<script src="../jquery.js">`

Comment: What is EJS? What I want is to use jQuery on the client side.

Comment: The problem with `<script src="../jquery.js">` is that the path is interpreted as localhost:3000/../jquery.js (the app is running on the port 3000), and the file is not found. I have to put the absolute path localhost/.../jquery.js which is dirty.

Comment: You're going to have to share more of your code. It should look something like this though : `<script src="/javascripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Arnaud Okay so let me clarify something. `<script src="localhost:3000//../jquery` works, but `<script src="../jquery` doesn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57465/discussion-between-krikara-and-arnaud).